# React JSX access to another component

Tags: reactjs

```
const MenteeCardPDF = ({}) => {
  const function = () => {
    something
  }
  return (
    <>
     <div>Hello World</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

If I want to access the HTML part of this component in another component.

Comment: Import the above component in another component and use it as a tag wherever required

Comment: Are you just asking how to *use* a component in React, as the comment above and answer below imply?  For that it seems that some introductory tutorials are the place to start.  Or are you asking something else?  (For example, why is there a function in this component?)  The question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Add `export default MenteeCardPDF` at the bottom.
This allows you to import this file in another component like this: `import MenteeCardPDF from '...'`
Then you can use it as a tag where needed: `<MenteeCardPDF/>`